Why isn't quantum error correction used in quantum key distribution protocols like BB84?
In QKD protocols like BB84 there are some post-processing steps after obtaining the sifted key. One of them is error correction so that Alice and Bob end up with the same string of bits. This is to account for noise in the quantum channel so for example if Alice sends a |+> because of noise a |0> could reach Bob instead.
Why isn't quantum error correction used in the quantum channel instead of just error correction in the post-processing? Wouldn't this improve the protocol since with quantum error correction if Alice sends a |+> Bob is going to receive a |+> and they can be sure that any alteration is due to Eve's eavesdropping.

I do not feel an expert on this topic but I have recently encountered QKD protocol variants that make use of quantum error correction, so maybe you will find this interesting: in Chapter 12.6 of the textbook by Nielsen and Chuang you can find a quantum-error correction QKD protocol called "modiﬁed Lo–Chau protocol" and its simplification that makes use of Calderbank-Shor-Steane codes. It is also briefly described in the QKD textbook written by Ramona Wolf, and she also mentions it here in her lecture series on-line. These protocols are mentioned in the context of proving the security of BB84 protocol, and I think that they were created exactly with this goal in mind (to help prove the security of BB84).
Generally, classical error correction is easier to perform than quantum error correction. To perform quantum error correction on a single logical qubit you need several additional physical qubits, and you need to perform quantum computation on them. This is much more challenging than simply preparing a single qubit in some state, sending it via a quantum channel, measuring on the other side, and then performing classical error correction.
Moreover, I do not see how using quantum error correction could provide gains in security. The errors during transmission can occur just the same way they did before - either due to noise, or to Eve's influence. Quantum error correction will allow Bob and Alice to correct the errors but I don't think it would enable them to determine if the error was caused by Eve or by some other interaction with the environment. One way or another, you have to assume that any error during transmission could have been caused by an eavesdropper.

Without error correction, QKD requires the sender to transmit four possible values and the receiver to measure in two possible bases.
With error correction, you will need to:

Store qubits. Otherwise the quantum information won't be around later, when you need to apply the corrections.
Interact qubits. Otherwise you won't be able to measure the stabilizers of the error correcting codes.
Adapt operations. Alice and Bob need to coordinate on what corrections to apply, instead of both parties being able to work essentially independently.
Tolerate faults. Because you are doing so much more idling and so many more operations than before, you need to correct errors that occur during the error correction.

Essentially, by adding error correction, you have changed the spec from "measure in two bases" to "build a full scale fault tolerant quantum computer". That's probably why you don't see it much (yet). Or, if you do, it's the absolute bare minimum error correction possible such as "Send two Bell pairs alongside a parity bit and do a single parity check between them using a single CNOT gate. Only discard later, during the classical postprocessing.".
